# Spooled files limited to 1GB size

Tags: ulimit

I have a shell script that creates a file by spooling from a database table using sqlplus. However, whenever the size of the spooled file reaches 1GB, the program terminates without any warning or error. On checking the ulimit (ulimit -a), I found that all values are set to unlimited. Also, there is no condition in the original script which limits the size. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Output of `df -h .` run in the target spool directory, please. Add this to your question, not here in the comments.

Comment: How is the script extracting your data?  Is `sqlplus` configured to abort if a dump size exceeds 1GB?

Comment: the sqlplus call is as below:-
sqlplus -S $DATABASE @file.sql $EXPORT_PATH